# Prim Algorithm application

Tags: c++, graph, graph-algorithm, minimum-spanning-tree

everyone, I have a weighted connected undirected graph, I need to find it's minimum spanning tree weight. On input I have numbers n(vertices amount), m(edges amount). And then m edges in format: A(out vert), B(in vert), C(weight). Here is input example:

```
3 3
1 2 1
2 3 2
3 1 3
```

I see it as a typical Prim algorithm, so I used it, but some tests are telling me that my code gives a wrong answer. Here it is:

```
#include <numeric>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

long long primAlgo(const int vertices, const vector<vector<long long>> &edges) {
    vector<bool> visited(vertices, false);
    vector<long long> minimal(vertices, 30001);

    minimal[0] = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i != vertices; ++i) {
        int vert = -1;
        for (size_t option = 0; option != vertices; ++option) {
            if (!visited[option] && (vert == -1 || minimal[option] < minimal[vert]))
                vert = option;
        }
        visited[vert] = true;

        for (size_t to = 0; to != vertices; ++to) {
            if (edges[vert][to] < minimal[to]) {
               minimal[to] = edges[vert][to];
            }
        }
    }

    long long sum = 0;

    for (size_t i = 0; i != vertices; ++i) {
        sum += minimal[i];
    }
    return sum;
}

int main() {
    int n, m;
    cin >> n >> m;
    int A, B;
    long long C;
    vector<vector<long long>> l(n, vector<long long> (n, 30001));
    for (size_t i = 0; i != m; ++i) {
        cin >> A >> B >> C;
        l[A - 1][B - 1] = C;
        l[B - 1][A - 1] = C;
    }

    long long ans = primAlgo(n, l);
    cout << ans;
}
```

So I was wondering, if you know, what the problem may be.

Comment: you should add a specific failing test

Comment: Why not use boost graph?  For a few lines of code you get access to a tested implementation.  Here is an example, using the kruskal algorithm, https://github.com/JamesBremner/PathFinder/blob/bdb50d7e80e6af3ed72c8fb7b81047e4f0fcc046/src/cPathFinder.cpp#L72-L92